# Using Appium to automate Mobile Safari on real device and encountering uncaught exceptions

Tags: java, ios, selenium, junit, appium

Using latest appium version to communicate to my fully provisioned iOS 7 device.

I can get Webdriver to build and and talk to my appium server.

I can get SafariLauncher to build from xcode and run on my device.

But when I try to use my java code to use the appium server to call SafariLauncher and run it on my device- I get the following "uncaughtException"

I've tried letting appium use its own version of SafariLauncher and I get a slightly different but no less blocking error that states "a new session could not be created". After switching the desired capabilities to my own locally built version of SafariLauncher.app, I'm getting the fresh "uncaughtException" error.

---

```
*info: Welcome to Appium v0.14.2
info: Appium REST http interface listener started on 0.0.0.0:3001
   info  - socket.io started
info: Spawning instruments force-quitting watcher process
info: [FQInstruments] Force quit unresponsive instruments v0.0.1
info: Responding to client with success: {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"0.14.2","revision":"113e796b850b28e7066fe472faf8554b73b6299d"}}}
debug: Appium request initiated at /wd/hub/status
GET /wd/hub/status 200 8ms - 144b
debug: Request received with params: {}
debug: Appium request initiated at /wd/hub/session
debug: Request received with params: {"desiredCapabilities":{"app":"/Users/accesso/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SafariLauncher-cquscfvgyludjdaolkpikgbmowez/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/SafariLauncher.app","device":"iphone"}}
info: Using local app from desiredCaps: /Users/accesso/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SafariLauncher-cquscfvgyludjdaolkpikgbmowez/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/SafariLauncher.app
info: Creating new appium session a84fee15-6d72-41d2-8ebb-4c8860455c2a
info: Removing any remaining instruments sockets
info: Cleaned up instruments socket /tmp/instruments_sock
warn: Could not parse plist file at /Users/accesso/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SafariLauncher-cquscfvgyludjdaolkpikgbmowez/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/SafariLauncher.app/en.lproj/Localizable.strings
info: Not setting locale because we're using a real device
info: Not setting iOS and app preferences since we're on a real device
info: Starting iOS device log capture via idevicesyslog
info: Not setting device type since we're connected to a device
error: uncaughtException: undefined date=Thu Feb 06 2014 10:17:25 GMT-0500 (EST), pid=3350, uid=501, gid=20, cwd=/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium, execPath=/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node/bin/node, version=v0.10.17, argv=[/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node/bin/node, /Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/lib/server/main.js, --port, 3001, --app, /, --udid, 7cc3dc5cc930406e9ce0e9f721a8e21b1eadfebc, --session-override, --keep-artifacts], rss=46399488, heapTotal=34235136, heapUsed=17620112, loadavg=[1.60546875, 1.29833984375, 1.205078125], uptime=84958, trace=[], stack=undefined*
```

---

Here is the script I'm trying to run-

```
import static org.junit.Assume.assumeTrue;



import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.Platform;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.safari.SafariDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;
import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.junit.runners.JUnit4;

@RunWith(JUnit4.class)
public class test {


    WebDriver driver;


  private static boolean isSupportedPlatform() {
    Platform current = Platform.getCurrent();
    return Platform.MAC.is(current) || Platform.WINDOWS.is(current);

  }

  @Before

  synchronized public void createDriver() {
    assumeTrue(isSupportedPlatform());

    try {
        //setup the web driver and launch the webview app.
        DesiredCapabilities desiredCapabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
        desiredCapabilities.setCapability("app", "/Users/accesso/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SafariLauncher-cquscfvgyludjdaolkpikgbmowez/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/SafariLauncher.app");
        desiredCapabilities.setCapability("device", "iphone");
        URL url = new URL("http://0.0.0.0:3001/wd/hub");
        driver = new RemoteWebDriver(url, desiredCapabilities);
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

  }

  @After
  public void quitDriver() {
    driver.quit();
  }

  @Test
  public void shouldBeAbleToPerformAGoogleSearch() {
    driver.get("http://store.accesso.com/CF-KBF");

  }
}
```

Comment: This link may be of some help.... https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/appium-discuss/D8N7bxtcZyw

Comment: Did you check if the uiautomation is on in settings?

Answer (score 0):

Try Appium latest 15 version.

I faced same problem of **"error: uncaughtException: undefined date"** updating Appium version resolved it.

I was using MAC mini and IPAD with APPIUM.